# Define complex antiderivative up to constant in terms of real definite integral

Tags: calculus

I know there's a complex analogue of the real antiderivative that is allowed to produce multivalued functions. For instance, the complex logarithm has some relationship to $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ .

Is it possible to define a potentially multi-valued complex antiderivative in terms of (one of the formalizations of) the real definite integral?

---

Here's my attempt so far.

The ordinary fundamental theorem of calculus relates the antiderivative to the definite integral of a real function.

$$ F(x) - F(0) = \int_0^x f(t) \cdot \mathrm{d}t $$

The fundamental theorem of calculus can also be thought of as a definition, giving us an operator $J$ from real functions to real functions.

$$ J(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \int_0^x f(t) \cdot \mathrm{d}t $$

Via a change of variable, we can replace $t$ with a function $\gamma(t)$ . So, $t$ = $\gamma(t)$ and $\mathrm{d}t = \gamma'(t) \mathrm{d}t $ . I'm to insist that $\gamma$ have at least one contiuous derivative.

$$ J(x) = \int_0^a f \circ \gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)\mathrm{d} t \;\;\text{where}\; \gamma(a)=x $$

If $\int$ is an ordinary Riemann integral, then I think the integrand expression can be from any vector space over the reals.

Let's call $\gamma$ the *path of integration*, since it seems somewhat path-like. In the real case, I think it's clear that the specific path of integration doesn't matter and only the endpoints do.

Let $C_1$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ with at least one continuous derivative.

Let $f$ be a continuous complex function.

$$ (Hf)(\alpha) = \left\{ \int_0^\alpha f \circ \gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t) \mathrm{d} t \mathop{:} \gamma \in C_1 \land \gamma(0) = 0 \land \gamma(x) = a \right\} $$

Then I think we can define $J$ like this.

$$ (Jf)(\alpha) = w \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \{w\} = (Hf)(\alpha) $$

I think this works for certain nice functions like monomials $z \mapsto z^n $ where $n$ is non-negative.

I'm stuck on how to generalize it.